# cocoa accept international numbers

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization, numbers

I have a calendar and can make local month names and short weekday names, for example weekdaynames with:

```
NSArray *weekdayNames = [[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease] shortWeekdaySymbols];
```

How can I localize these?

For example:

```
a daycounter i = 1..31

daystr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" %i", daycounter];}
```

I get `fine 1...31` in latin Numbers

What do I have to change/add that I get for example Arabic Numbers, Chinese Numbers etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it now with:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    daystr = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:daycounter]];
    [formatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the restrictions altogether.

```
daystr = [NSString stringWithString: @" %s", daycounter];}
```

Comment: ?? daycounter is a Integer (sorry i may have not been explizit.
DayCounter is a INTEGER and Daystr have to be NSString

Comment: *explicit* and obviously you would have to change daycounter to a string.